# Generic covariance workarounds?

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have bullets:

```
public LaserBullets : Projectile
```

I have a gun that inherits from a base weapon with the bullet type that goes with the derived gun:

```
public LaserWeapon : Weapon<LaserBullets>
```

I have a property to establish the current weapon of a player:

```
public Weapon<Projectile> CurrentWeapon
{
    set { currentWeapon = value; }
}
```

This fails (cannot implicitly cast `LaserWeapon` to `Weapon<Projectile>`)

```
player.CurrentWeapon = new LaserWeapon();
```

I've read about no support for certain covariance in C#, but I don't want to think that I'm stuck here. Is there any way to make my situation work? I'm trying to maintain a base weapon in the player class but work with a more specific weapon in another class.

I tried creating my own cast operator for LaserWeapon but I got an error about being unable to cast to/from base class.

Comment: I thought this would work, but I'll take your word that it doesn't.  What if you make a `Weapon` base class that `Weapon<TProjectile>` derives from? And then make `CurrentWeapon` just a `Weapon`?

Comment: I'll see about it. But it might be a problem because `Weapon<TProjectile>` has an abstract method `Fire()` that returns `TProjectile`. `Player` calls this method on the base class. Which leads to another type of covariance problem where specifying a base return type and overriding with a derived return type has compile time issues as well.

Comment: I believe @JonathonReinhart is correct - in my experience, I've always used a non-generic base class or an Interface in this type of scenario.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart It's not possible because it's not typesafe. If it was allowed, you could assign a `List<string>` to a variable of type `List<object>`, and then add anything to the list of strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your example would have worked if `Weapon<T>` was a covariant interface declared like so:

```
public interface Weapon<out TProjectile>
{
}
```

This will only work where `TProjectile` is used as a return value, e.g:

```
TProjectile Fire();
```

But will **NOT** work where `TProjectile` is used as an input parameter, e.g:

```
LoadClip(IEnumerable<TProjectile> ammo);
```

From your comments, I can see you're after the generic return value, so make an interface as follows:

```
public interface IWeapon<out TProjectile> where TProjectile : Projectile
{
    TProjectile Fire();
}
```

Then use this interface implementation; There is nothing stopping you from having a useful base class, e.g.

```
public abstract class Weapon<TProjectile> : IWeapon<TProjectile> where TProjectile : Projectile
{
    public abstract TProjectile Fire();
}
```

As long as your player class is along the lines of:

```
public class Player
{
    public IWeapon<Projectile> CurrentWeapon { get; set; }
}
```

This allows you to still use `CurrentWeapon.Fire()` which will return an instance of `Projectile`.

Comment: Thanks so much. I've learned a lot from your response and it appears to have worked for my specific scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Make a non-generic class `Weapon` that `Weapon<T>` inherits. Use that class instead of `Weapon<Projectile>` in your code.